# Passenger affects cookie expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

When I start project by passenger (passenger start) and try set cookie expires, I get cookie from web server that already outdated.

```
In console:

passenger start

In controller:

cookies[:auth_admin_token] = {
  :value    => 'auth_cookie',
  :path     => '/settings',
  :secure   => false,
  :expires  => 20.minutes.from_now
}
```

As I found the problem related to Time zone stated by Rails. But not found any info about Time zone and cookie in rails documentation. The cookie will work if I set big value for expires "240.minutes.from_now".

I have no such problems when I start project by "WEBrick"

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.20 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Comment: What are the raw HTTP response headers that you get from Phusion Passenger and from WEBrick, and how do they differ?

Comment: I put output to gist https://gist.github.com/shaliko/6130351

Comment: Your auth_cookie appears in neither of the responses. It's probably broken in both cases, but your browser happens to be caching an old cookie when accessing the WEBrick port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was passenger bug "Autogenerated Date header must be in GMT" https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=913

Bug was fixed in passenger version 4.0.13 http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/08/15/phusion-passenger-4-0-13-released/

"Autogenerated HTTP Date headers are now in UTC instead of local time. This could cause cookies to have the wrong expiration time. Fixes issue #913."

Comment: Can confirm this solution. Mark your answer as correct, please.